# jQuery not selector doesn't appear to work with class

Tags: jquery, html, dom, cross-browser, selector

Ok another dumb jQuery question...

The `not` selector in jQuery is giving me problems. **I'm trying to select all but the first element having a given class `toggle-button`.** But I can have this dialogue with the console...

```
? $('.toggle-button').length
4
? $('.toggle-button:not(:eq(0))').length
4
```

No difference. But...

```
? $('div').length
23
? $('div:not(:eq(0))').length
22
```

What gives, Resig?

Why does the `not` selector have different behaviour when applied to a class (seemingly) - and how can I do the select I want in the most idiomatic jQuery way?

`:not(:first)` does the same thing...

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all responses. This looks to be a bug in the jQuery/IE partnership.

Solutions...

```
$('.toggle-button').filter(':gt(0)')

$('.toggle-button').not(':first')

$('.toggle-button').slice(0);
```

...and no doubt many more. I'll leave it to the crazies to figure which is best :D

Comment: Works for me [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/5gSxP/). Maybe there is something else in your code preventing the expected behavior.

Comment: @DidierGhys Thanks, looks like this is an Internet Exploder issue (:O) as it works in Chrome for me but not IE....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any non-CSS filtering/selecting should be done through jQuery methods, as it means that jQuery is unable to use CSS to speed up the selector. It tries to use the native CSS support in the browser but if you use `:not` or `:eq` etc, it has to use its own parsing system which is slower.

The air-quotes "correct" way is this:

```
$('.toggle-button').filter(':gt(0)').length;
```

As to why the `:not` behaves differently, I'm not sure. I'll keep thinking, and if I get a lightbulb, I'll update this answer :)

---

Edit: It looks like its some browser-specific quirk - I've just done

- `$('.prettyprint').length` - 3
- `$('.prettyprint:not(:eq(0))').length` - 2
- `$('.question-header').length` - 1
- `$('.question-header:not(:eq(0))').length` - 0

For this page, at the time I did them, those numbers were right and predictable. Double check your code for silly typos, and that kind of thing, because it looks to be working OK here.

---

Edit Edit: It's an IE8 bug, presumably to do with the CSS selection engine it uses. See http://jsfiddle.net/5gSxP/2/ for a rundown of the 3 selection methods, the first one fails in IE8 but the one in this answer works OK.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I really wanted to know *why* though! I'll await your lightbulb. Are you saying that `gt` uses native CSS?

Comment: Had a small lightbulb, see post :P And no, `:gt` doesn't use CSS which is why it's in the `.filter()` instead of in the main selector. The general rule of thumb is "If it's a CSS selector, it goes in `$()`, otherwise it goes in `.filter()`, `.not()`, `.find()`, etc - jQuery selection methods.

Comment: Tested in IE8 with Didier's jsFiddle, and updated with my method - works as expected in IE8 :) http://jsfiddle.net/5gSxP/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work and more readable with `.not()`:

```
$('div').not(':first').length;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works too - although my selector would be `$('.toggle-button')...` :)